# Menu with argument from views

Tags: 7, views, routes

I want to create menu block for each user on sidebar.
In it there would be links like Videos, Images, Bio.

So i made view with argument and url is usertype/%/videogallery

It is working fine, but how can i add this as a menu item so when someone visits user3 profile the url in the block menu is leading to Videos, Images Bio with url usertype/user3/videogallery

Answer (score 0):

Just use views to create a block with your "menu" links and then make it show up in the sidebar for all "usertype/*" and "usertype/*/*" pages.

That view will also need a contextual filter "userid from url" similar to your other view. You can "rewrite the url" to create the links.

Comment: I tried to do what you said and got some result but not perfect. I used same view and created block, added "link" field, rewriten result, in text area added "Video Gallery". Since i have 3 nodes in VideoGallery i got 3x "Video Gallery" linking to each node. I want to have 1 link that leads to view of video gallery.

Comment: sorry, should have been more specific. You'll need a view of users, not nodes.